# Questions being marked "off-topic" for the wrong reason(s)

Tags: discussion

I'm calling out the users [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg), [yohbs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/367/yohbs), [Cassini](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27/cassini), [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao), and [Jim Baldwin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/19758/jim-baldwin) for putting my question on hold unfairly because according to them my [last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/148559/optimal-bankroll-allocation-placing-multiple-bets-simultaneously?noredirect=1#comment398800_148559) had nothing to do with Mathematica. This [other question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121292/sound-synthesizer-using-manipulate) of mine had nothing to do with Mathematica, but like the one before it, it was about solving a math problem USING MATHEMATICA. The last question was marked "favorite" twice. The first question was put on hold as "off-topic." What I asked in both was similar: "Help me solve this one problem using Mathematica." Now I suspect (not an accusation) these users dumped my recent question into oblivion just because they couldn't provide a good answer themselves or didn't particularly understand the concept I was touching. They didn't even tell me why the ArgMax[] function returned an error message, and that was a technical Mathematica problem they could've provided an explanation for. This is gross incompetence and I denounce this type of behaviour within this growing community: "If I like this question, I give it an answer or comment it; if i don't get it, I mark it off-topic." Despicable.

P.D. If the question had more much to do with math than Wolfram Language in Mathematica, it could've easily been migrated to the proper forum. This doesn't appear to be the case as I see it.

Comment: "They didn't even tell me why the ArgMax[] function returned an error message" The explicit question is, "How should I split my bankroll between the two in order to maximize the long term Expected value of this wager?", and your question does not mention you get an error message (I get no messages).  You say, "I don't understand the output," but the output `{0.,1.}` seems pretty clear to me (and correct).  Everything seems to work.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your response. Now I'm fairly confident the output error was due to a bug in the Development Platform online I was using. I did not test it on the native desktop application Mathematica. Wolfram Alpha handles the ArgMax [] function with similar parameters better than the Development Platform for some reason.

Comment: The output {0,1} is what I get outside the Development Platform, precisely. And that I understand.

Answer (score 11):

I maintain that the comments thread made it perfectly clear why your 2nd question was closed, so I will not reiterate the thread. I further maintain that it is ***your*** responsibility to formulate your questions so as to make them attractive to those who answer questions.

Posting a question does not confer the right to an answer. The community, by its response, decides on the disposal of a question. Keep in mind that  we who answer are all volunteers.

Your question was closed by five high rep members of the community. I am confident that each vote was carefully considered. Mine certainly was. I put considerable time into reviewing the code you posted before I casted my close vote.

As to the reason given, I considered giving this one, but decided not to.

> there is no well-posed question in this post; the OP is simply begging for somebody to act as a free debugging service.

I don't use that one very often because the community considers it rather harsh, but perhaps you would have considered it more appropriate.

Comment: "(...) the OP is simply begging for somebody to act as a free debugging service." Well, isn't that precisely the idea behind these forums within Stack Exchange?! Particularly those having to do with computing. Unacceptable excuse! The fact all members are all volunteers ("free service"!) or that they enjoy a very high reputation doesn't confer your case any more laudability against my case. I maintain the validity of my closed question through a solid analogy with another thread of mine that went all right.

Comment: I see that you have failed to conjure up a considerable excuse to vote down my question. Your last words on it were that you would refrain from voting it down, if someone managed to provide an answer. Closing down a question just because every reputable member failed to provide an answer doesn't speak well of anyone. Nor is it a sound argument for what happened. Other than that, I appreciate, the fact you had the diligence to respond here unlike the other 4 that cowardly thumbed me down without making their voices heard.

Comment: I forget to point out that my initial complain was about the question being put off-topic, not about people failing to answer it. Here you make it seem like I was solely and explicitly complaining about people not answering it. Faulty reasoning on your behalf. Now I'm fairly confident my initial intuition was quite correct: the question was marked off-topic out of disdain.